# How to set SPI clock speed for MT7623N

Tags: spi, clock, programming, hardware, clock-speed

first I must say, I am new to the HW programming, but I really enjoy it.

My first project is writing a library for MT7623N (BananaPi R2) that handles GPIO pins. I got the GPIO part done and I can set pin HIGH or LOW and now I moved to SPI, which didn't seem as a big problem either, but..

I got stuck on the clock for SPI. I don't know how to properly set clock speed, because there is no mention of clock divider.
I understood, that the clock speed is selected through clock multiplixer.
[image: clock multiplixer]

**List of PLL is below**
Here starts my first issue. SYSPLL is probably misnamed MAINPLL? And what does SYSPLL_**D4** mean? I am guessing, that it means frequency dividing by value 100, which should be /2, so for MAINPLL with frequency 2184MHz, it should be 1092Mhz. Is that correct? I haven't found any mention about this in the datasheet itself.

Then there is UNIVPLL**2**_D2. Only one UNIVPLL is documented. Does it mean multiplication? So the value is UNIVPLL*2/2

I am trying to calculate values for the SPI0 MUX. Can you please help? I am guessing that the first (default) clock is 26Mhz? I would like to use much lower values.

[image]

[image]

The datasheet reference https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GwXa5BNJFExP4HFEBcDFKAHYCWC46bdA/view

Thank you very much for any kind of hint! I am stuck on this second day.

Here are the PLL frequencies

[image: PLL frequencies]

Comment: Just an update: I found out, that I can actually modify clock speed by modifying the length of the LOW and HIGH values, but my main question still stands :/

Comment: Baud rate of SCLK is derived from whichever clock you choose for SPI. Baud rate should be configurable using some SPI register in your controller. It has to be in the datasheet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understood it just like you said and I identified the multiplixor which handles which clock it uses, but I don't know what are the values of the clock. I think that they are written as convention-based rather than defined in the datasheet. For example - how do I calculate speed for SYSPLL_D3? It is all in the question. @MituRaj

Comment: Turns out, I still don't know the speed of the SPI clock. I thought that the speed is 26MHz, but inside the documentation there is a "description" for some flags, where the SPI cycle is 7.519ns, which is 133MHz. Can anybody please help understanding it?  I tried to provide all info inside the question. If there is anything missing, let me know please.